# How to save a list of strings in arduino?

Tags: c, arduino, eeprom

I want to create a list of names on my Arduino. I want to be able to add a name to the list, I want to be able to remove a certain name from the list and I want to be able to check if a certain name exists in the list.

As far as I understand I need to use something called EEPROM?

BTW. I might gotten something all wrong, please tell me.

Comment: [EEPROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM) is a non-volatile memory (i.e. it will keep its content between boots and with no power). It's where you would store permanent data that should live between boots. Does this list of your need to be stored between boots? Then you could just [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) a list that you have in RAM (which you should do anyway, create the list in RAM (heap) and then serialize it to non-volatile storage).

Comment: As for the list itself, you *do* know how to create simple linked lists?

Comment: I was not very specific. Yes, I need the list to be store when the unit is without power. And yes, I do know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

EEPROM means programmable for multiple times. Not mean storage. If you want to store list while the device is running, it is possible. Define an array like standard way. You can search in that array, add names to array by using arduino console. These are depends on your code.

But if you want to store your array all the time (even device is closed) you need a storage device such as sd card or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [store data in the EEPROM](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM), but depending on the Arduino model there isn't much space. You would be better off using an SD card shield.